# Prepositions 'to', 'for', or 'about'

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct and why:

- We're waiting for a response **to** our request.
- We're waiting for a response **for** our request.
- We're waiting for a response **about** our request.

Comment: **None!** We are waiting **for** a response *to* our request.

Comment: Detailed explanations about prepositions and when to use which are [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/prepositions.htm)

Comment: Jejeje, you're right, I mistyped that part of the sentence and afterwards I copy-pasted it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

As Maulik mentioned, it is

> We're waiting ***for*** a response ***to*** our request.

Alternatively, you could say,

> We're ***awaiting*** a response ***to*** our request.